# No sound from Ubuntu 13.10 after selecting output

Tags: drivers, sound, 13.10, headphones, output

Hello I have headphones that I plug and unplug from time to time because I talk on Skype. When I unplugged my headphones from my keyboard there was no sound from my speakers
while I was playing music. I tried rebooting my computer and it didn't work.
I have the right output selected and everything.

Comment: Can you check that the Volume control isn't muted, sometimes this can be easily overlooked.

Comment: It is not muted I have already checked this before.